# height of block with view containing exposed filter

Tags: theming, blocks, views

I have created a block with a view containing an exposed filter (drop downbox, auto submit).
Based on the selection in the dropdown, the visitor will see a short or long list of results. This block is located in the content region of one particular node.

The height of the block does adapt to this result, but unfortunately all elements below this block (i.e. the footer region) do not go below this block. They just remain on the initial height as when the page loaded.

How can I tell the footer to go below the block with the view automatically each time the filter is changed?

Your step-by-step help is highly appreciated!

Regards,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

Some html element wrapping the block has a fixed height. This height gets set the first time you load the page and thereafter it does not change (it could be done by a jQuery script). You will need to hunt it down in your web dev tools and alter it with a CSS rule that sets the height to auto, or you might even have to do it via jQuery.

Try with another theme (bartik) and see if it also happens. If it does not then it is theme related.

If you cant get it fixed then I suggest you create a custom region just below the content region that is used solely for the block. Just use a div for the custom region and only set the width if need be. On a block level element the height should by default be auto.

Look [here](http://megadrupal.com/blog/add-new-regions-in-drupal-7-themes) how to add custom region.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to inform you fellow drupalists, that a solution was provided to me and solved my problem.

The reason was a config setting in the (omega) theme to use equal heights. Desactivating this, solved my problem.

Hope this helps you as well.

Regards,
Hans